# Redis - subset of querying hashes and then sorting alphabetically on a value of the hash

Tags: redis

In my application users can favourite pages - I store these in a set

```
user:123:favourites
    456, 671, 106, 507, 789
```

I also store a hash of information for each page

```
page:1
    title: "foo"
    owner_name: "jim"
page:2
    title: "bar"
    owner_name: "tim"
....
page:n
    title: "title-n"
    owner_name: "owner-n"
```

I'm trying to do the following

1. Get the set of favourite pages
2. Get the page objects from the hashes
3. Sort the page hashes by title
4. Return a subset of the pages (for paging results - 1-3 or 4-6)

I'm still quite new to redis so kind of struggling to get my head around if this is possible and if I should even be using redis this way.

What steps here should be completed on the redis side and what steps should be completed on the application side?

---

Here's my guess, I'll try it later

```
SORT user:123:favourites BY page:* -> title GET # LIMIT 0 2 ALPHA DESC
```

Comment: I didn't get what are the hashes 1-3. You should read about `SORT` command.

Comment: @Niloct - I've updated my question, hopefully this clears up what i'm trying to achieve?